# Autocomplete textview not showing dropdown when there is only 1 predictions coming from google places api

Tags: android

public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {

```
private static final String LOG_TAG = "Roomys";

private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

private static final String API_KEY = "Akalkcalckalaxlxxkalxii22leilkala";

private ArrayList<String> resultList;

public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return resultList.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int index) {
    return resultList.get(index);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            Log.d("getFilter","constraint is "+constraint);
            if (constraint != null) {
                // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                filterResults.values = resultList;
                filterResults.count = resultList.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                Log.d("publishing results","true");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    return filter;
}

private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
        Log.i("search api uri", sb.toString());
        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
    if(jsonResults!=null){
        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");
            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
 resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                Log.d("places auto","description is "+predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                Log.d("places auto","result list size is "+resultList.size());
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
}
```

the usage code

```
    actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.home_address_act);
    PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter adapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.autocomplete_list_item);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);
    actv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

getting text.

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    address = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Log.d("places autocomplete","selected place is "+address);

}
```

please help me, this is a problem since i also want to calculate lat n long from this places and no place showing up that i want to enter. But my friend's php website google places works properly. Is this a problem with android

and here is the json response that shows 1 prediction properly.

```
  {        
       "predictions" : [
  {
     "description" : "UBCI Gremda, C81, Sfax, Tunisia",
     "id" : "f4c3384175d71788cbfd6ff7ee1809b893d55dbf",
     "matched_substrings" : [
        {
           "length" : 7,
           "offset" : 0
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "ChIJy5CYbYTTARMRLlJ_ciDn0FA",
     "reference" : "CjQtAAAAdA8G1_eaEc6ojJye079YMzIGLTW8h14KpcERlGzD8RYR4LWM9asStZFqNm2kRq7QEhCB9ge0-NYjo15-2304DKG0GhQv-Al8uWn7V7o7HhrMA9BvVWMGcA",
     "terms" : [
        {
           "offset" : 0,
           "value" : "UBCI Gremda"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 13,
           "value" : "C81"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 18,
           "value" : "Sfax"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 24,
           "value" : "Tunisia"
        }
     ],
     "types" : [ "establishment" ]
  }    
   ],    
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

there is one prediction and m getting this properly in array adapter but auto complete doesnt show this single result drop down when i enter "UBCI gr" it just stops.

Comment: can you please show your layout / xml part of AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: Please check your android:completionThreshold value in layout xml and also first try for some dummy data.

Comment: @AjinkyaS I guess...android:completionThreshold will not help OP.....as he isn't concerned about getting result on typing more or less characters.........instead he wants to get results even if only single is available

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra i am getting results successfully when there's more then one prediction results but not when there's only one..
For ex: "UBCI gr", "Cafe caraw".. the link shows results properly and also saved to resultlist properly.. only thing is autocomplete does not show drop down.

Comment: @AmitTumkur yes, I got it.

Comment: here's my autocomplete_list_item used

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:padding="4dp"
          android:textColor="#000"/>

Comment: @DroidWormNarendras sir is it a issue with autocomplete text or is it that autocomplete requires more then one field to show drop down ?? I even checked this on google maps, it shows up this "UBCI Gremda" and also checked my friend's php website who has used google places search, there also its working fine. And i also noticed that this old coding is no more available android developer docs, they have changed it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "UBCI Gremda, C81, Sfax, Tunisia" is a French-language result. You can get it to appear correctly by adding "&language=fr" to the URL. Otherwise, the Places API Web Service may default to the English language, which does not include that result.

I'd also suggest looking into the new Places API for Android, which should be a bit simpler to use. See https://developers.google.com/places/android/ for the documentation.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Bro thanks for ur answer and i tried this too. I still get same prediction which is only 1 but instead of Tunisia it was Tunisie. And i also tried couple  
of other languages and i get the results properly. I guess that auto complete view not showing drop down when the adapter has a arraylist of size 1. And y this is happening i have no idea. If anyone wud point out the mistake then i wud b most happy.

Comment: Just to clarify, did you add:

`sb.append("&language=fr");`

in your code?

Comment: yup.. I just want to knw one thing that will auto complete wil show drop down or not when the adapter set to it has a arraylist of size 1 only ??